# slicing dynamically in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, slice

I have a Python 3.x script which only has the following function:

```
from random import random

def slicer(longitude):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    result = ""
    x = 0

    for i in range(1, int(longitude)):
        x = int(62 * random())
        if x == 0:
            x += 1
        else:
            # get a random letter from alphabet, seem this is the problem > (alphabet[x:1]):
            string_section = alphabet[x:1]
            result = result + string_section
    return result

print(str(slicer(10)))  # get a 10 digit string
```

But this code doesn't work, and I'm stuck...

Is `s[x:1]` permitted, where `x` is a changing value from a for loop?

If not, is there another method that will accomplish the same result? Thanks for help.

Comment: remember that, in python slices, mylist[a:b] should have b > a if both a and b are non-negative. negative indexes x are mapped to (len(mylist)+x), so they count from the end.

Comment: The output should be a random string with n digits using the alphabet provided in the function. I know this could be realized with another method but I want use this method in particular. Curiosly, the script doesn't show any error, just a null result.

Comment: OH! so the problem, in effect was alphabet[x:1], this is solved changing it to: alphabet[x:x+1]...Thanks! I'm beginning with Python

Comment: null (None) or empty ("")?

Comment: Technically it is solved by using a length-1 slice (`alphabet[x:x+1]`) but this is a little misleading. You aren't trying to get a slice that happens to be length 1, you are trying to get a single element. It's probably better to code it that way, so that anyone reading the code sees from your choice that you meant just to get one item. Since `alphabet[x]` works, and it doesn't have the pitfalls of requesting a slice that falls outside of the range of indices of the iterable object, it's simpler and easier to understand in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is almost always less than 1, so `[x:1]` is a meaningless range. If I just do:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
alphabet[32:1]
```

I can see that python returns nothing. So your script is continually adding nothing to `result` -- what you need is `alphabet[x]` to take that position from the alphabet. And since `alphabet[0]` is `a`,  you don't need to add 1 if x is 0. (In your implementation, you'll never return an "a" and "b" is about twice as likely to come up than any other letter).

```
from random import random

def slicer(longitude):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    result = ""
    x = 0

    for i in range(1, int(longitude)):
        x = int(62 * random())
        string_section = alphabet[x]
        result = result + string_section
    return result

print(str(slicer(10)))  # get a 10 digit string
```

But ....

If you want to make sure you don't repeat letters, you can just use `random.sample()`:

```
import random

def slicer(longitude):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    result = random.sample(alphabet,longitude)
    return result

print(''.join(slicer(10)))  # Produces a list, use .join() to print a string
```

Answer (score 2):

You may access a single character from the `alphabet` at random position `x` simply with `alphabet[x]`. Note that `x` must be in the range `[0, len(alphabet)-1]` to be a valid index, so you might want to use `math.floor` instead of `int` when turning the random value into an integer to serve as an index.

Alternatively, you can use `random.choice` for `longitude` number of times:

```
result = ''
for i in xrange(longitude):
    result += random.choice(alphabet)
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a single character you don't need slice, a simple indexing would do `alphabet[x]`.